# table rows inside dom-repeat does not line up with headers outside dom-repeat

Tags: polymer-1.0

I have a simple element named "products". It is a table and I am rendering each product in the list as rows with a child element inside a dom-repeat. However, the columns don't line up even if I used a fixed width on both the parent and child. Does anyone know of a solution?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7uhx.png)

```
<template>
<style>

</style>
<tr>
  <th class="col1" style="min-width: 150px;" colspan="1">[[product.col1]]   </th>
  <td class="col2" colspan="1">[[product.col2]]</td>
  <td class="col3" colspan="1">[[product.col3]]</td>
  <td class="col4" colspan="1">[[product.col4]]</td>
  <td class="col5" colspan="1">[[product.col5]]</td>
  <td class="col6" colspan="1">[[product.col6]]</td>
  <td class="col7" colspan="1">[[product.col7]]</td>
  <td class="col8" colspan="1">[[product.col8]]</td>
</tr>
</template>

<dom-module id="product-item">

  <template>
    <tr>
      <th class="col1" style="min-width: 150px;" colspan="1">[[product.col1]]</th>
      <td class="col2" colspan="1">[[product.col2]]</td>
      <td class="col3" colspan="1">[[product.col3]]</td>
      <td class="col4" colspan="1">[[product.col4]]</td>
      <td class="col5" colspan="1">[[product.col5]]</td>
      <td class="col6" colspan="1">[[product.col6]]</td>
      <td class="col7" colspan="1">[[product.col7]]</td>
      <td class="col8" colspan="1">[[product.col8]]</td>
    </tr>
  </template>
```

[codepen here](https://jsfiddle.net/g516h2yr/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not supposed to work. `<table>`, `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, and `<tr>` don't not support custom elements as children.

Not even `<template>` is supported in all browsers (IE, Edge?,...) within these tags.

For the browser where `<template>` is actually working,
What you can do is to make `<product-item>` an element that extends `<tr>` and use it like

```
 <tbody>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{products}}">
      <tr is="product-item" product="{{item}}"></tr>
    </template>
  </tbody>
```

See https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements for more details.

Comment: brilliant, this is a good technique to know. All the columns are lined up after implementing your suggestion.

Comment: Glad to hear. Thanks for the feefback :-)